# Switch a TeX \macro and a script on a region of text

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, tex

How can I search and replace in a region of a (TeX)buffer all occurences of `\macro{foo}_{bar}` to `\macro{foo_{bar}}`, `foo` and `bar` not being "constants" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [regexp replacement](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html) (`M-x replace-regexp` or `C-M-%`) to replace a pattern with holes.

Assuming that `foo` and `bar` do not themselves contain braces or line breaks, replace `\\macro{\(.*?\)}_{\(.*?\)}` by `\\macro{\1_{\2}}`. Explanations (see the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html) for more details):

- `\` is a special character, so you need to write `\\` to match one backslash.
- `\(…\)` is a [group](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html#Backslash-in-Regular-Expressions): Emacs will remember what the group matched.
- `.*?` matches any sequence of characters except a line break. It stops as early as possible (whereas `.*` would stop as late as possible, and could thus end up matching all of `\macro{foo}_{bar} and more \stuff{baz}`).
- In the replacement, `\1` and `\2` are replaced by what the corresponding group matched.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much.